# What does this sentence mean in paragraph §3.2/2 of the C++11 Standard?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, one-definition-rule

The sentence is part of paragraph §3.2/2 :

> A variable whose name appears as a potentially-evaluated expression is
>   odr-used unless **it is an object that satisfies the requirements for
>   appearing in a constant expression (5.19) and the lvalue-to-rvalue
>   conversion (4.1) is immediately applied**.

What exactly does the sentence in bold mean above?

**Edit**:

The answer to the question of which this one is considered a duplicate, doesn't say anything that could answer my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means that when you use a constant as a constant, it's just like you were actually using a constant.

```
struct S {
  static const int i = 0;
};
int main() {
  return S::i;
}
```

Although `S::i` has an initialiser, it has no definition, but the text in your question makes a special exception for uses like this, where `S::i` is only accessed for its value. In that case, no definition is needed.

On the other hand, other uses do require a definition:

```
struct S {
  static const int i = 0;
};
int f(const int &i) {
  return i;
}
int main() {
  return f(S::i);
}
```

This program is invalid, and is accepted by some implementations, but rejected by others. The call to `f` requires an actual definition of `S::i` to exist, although if `f` gets inlined, it's possible for the lack of a definition to go undiagnosed.

On my system, if compiling and linking the second program without optimisations, I get:

```
$ g++ test2.cc -o test2
/tmp/ccdEsfxs.o:test2.cc:function main: error: undefined reference to 'S::i'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

To make it work, a definition needs to be provided, like so:

```
struct S {
  static const int i = 0;
};
const int S::i;
```

Comment: How would you relate the phrase "lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is immediately applied" to your first example?

Comment: What do you mean by "it has no definition"?

Comment: @WakeupBrazil `S::i` is an lvalue, it is used in the `return` statement in a function returning `int`. In that case, the lvalue needs to be (and is) converted to an rvalue. (It's not the fact that it's used in a `return` statement by itself: in a function returning `int &`, the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion would not be applied.)

Comment: @0x499602D2 That it has no definition. I'll update to give a linker error I can get for it, which will hopefully help clarify.

Comment: @hvd I'm talking about the "immediately" applied? What does that mean?

Comment: @WakeupBrazil In my second example, the lvalue `S::i` is passed to `f`, and it's only inside `f` that the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is applied. That means it's not immediately applied.

Comment: @hvd But how is it possible to conclude what you're saying from the phrase highlighted in my question?

Comment: @WakeupBrazil I don't see how you can read it any other way, so I don't know how to respond to that. The word "immediately" is simply used in its everyday English meaning. Can you clarify why you think that it's immediately applied in my second example, or why you don't think it's immediately applied in my first example?

Comment: Maybe I wasn't very clear. The Standard has this sentence: "A variable whose name appears as a potentially-evaluated expression is odr-used unless it is an object that satisfies the requirements for appearing in a constant expression (5.19) and the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1) is immediately applied.". Then you said this would turn your first snippet legal. My question is: am I supposed to guess this just by reading the Standard?

Comment: @WakeupBrazil Ah, okay, that I can understand. No, the standard is written the way it is to be as unambiguous as possible (so that every C++ compiler implements the same language), not to be as easy to read as possible. I agree that it is hard to figure out what is meant by it if you don't already know (or sort of know).